# Cannot boot windows 10 SSD after having installed Windows 11

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-11

1. Took original 512GB NVMe SSD with windows 10 install out of M.2_1 slot
2. Installed a 4TB NVMe SSD into M.2_1 slot
3. Installed Windows 11 from iso (using Ventoy)
4. Installed another new 2TB NVMe SSD into M.2_2 slot
5. Plugged original 512GB NVMe SSD into a USB3 NVMe/NGFF adapter. It shows as a JMicron adapter.
6. Booted to Clonezilla iso (using Ventoy)
7. Followed instructions in Clonezilla and cloned contents of 512GB SSD to 2TB SSD

Now, regardless of CSM being enabled in the motherboard's UEFI settings:

- 2TB drive won't boot, with a `0xc000000e winload.efi` error.
- original 512GB drive won't boot with a similar error, even if I move it from the JMicron USB3 adapter into the M.2_2 slot
- In the JMicron USB3 adapter the original 512GB drive also gives this error when attempting to boot from it on another computer. This is the hint for me that booting the working SSD from the USB3 adapter is probably bad, and also that this may have caused my clonezilla session to perform a bad clone.
- Booting the 4TB drive to boot to Windows 11 still works. I am so far trying to avoid physically removing this drive from M.2_1 slot because I want to keep its thermal pad intact.

My hope is that if I do put the original 512GB drive back in the M.2_1 slot that it might start to work again. I cannot fathom what the Win11 install or Clonezilla session could have possibly done to damage the contents of the 512GB drive.

Comment: Two SSD's.. both with Windows installed on them would mean there are multiple boot partitions involved here... which unless done properly through dual boot config = windows won't play ball. Can you confirm if the 2TB NVME will boot when it's the only thing plugged in on the primary NVME slot? There's a chance if you performed a device to device clone that the boot partition wasn't copied over.. clonezilla usually asks you to answer Y/N if you want to do that.

Comment: If you had Compatibility Support Mode enabled for Windows 10 (I think that is what you said) then Windows 11 changed it (Windows 11 does not allow CSM). So that may be why Windows 10 no longer boots..

Comment: Yeah this is interesting. Basically it looks like somehow Clonezilla borked my 512GB drive in the course of cloning it to the 2TB drive, when it was in the USB3 adapter. No matter what I did I can't make the 512GB drive bootable anymore in any computer. At the end of the day it's disappointing (especially how it's also impossible to tell the motherboard to disconnect an NVMe device, this seems impossible). I gave up and will just daily drive the new Win11 install from now on and copy my files and programs over. So far everything is cooperating on that front.

Comment: I will never install windows with more than one drive enabled in a system ever again.

Comment: @John CSM remains enabled (fTPM also switched off; i had to re-set the device PIN to log into Win11 though) and I am still booting into Windows 11. So either i'm interpreting what you wrote incorrectly or what you stated is incorrect. Although, maybe you are saying that windows 11 cannot install with CSM enabled? By the way CSM was also not enabled when I was running Windows 10. I have enabled it during the course of this troubleshooting, and it made no difference other than add a few more entries to the boot menu and make the UEFI splash screen look old-school (low-res).

Comment: Windows does not use legacy boot (CSM) . It will only install with UEFI enabled.

Comment: I suggest installing Windows 11 by itself for the time being without Windows 10. You should find within a week or two that you no longer need Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, I have given up and gone ahead and done that (restoring the apps and data I use into the new Win11 install) because I do know from experience the time-consuming and usually unfixable nature of boot problems in general. And also I realized my timeline has gotten fuzzy since I also now recall that at some point I attempted to run `bootrec /FixBoot` from a Windows installer when booted off of my Ventoy USB drive, which actually broke the Ventoy USB installation rendering it empty of ISO's. I suspect this may have also rendered my 512GB disk unbootable and I simply never checked it till this.